# How to mount Windows share using Kerberos with custom keytab automatically?

Tags: linux, mount, suse, kerberos

I have to mount a Samba share using Kerberos on a SLES 12 system automatically from boot on. The problem is, that the Kerberos ticket does not get automatically requested when trying to mount the share automatically, so I had to do a workaround using systemd-mounts.

But let me explain my situation a bit better:

First, manually requesting a Kerberos ticket and mounting the share works perfectly fine:

```
$ kinit service-user@example.com
$ sudo mount -vt cifs "//fileserver.example.com" -o username=service-user,cruid=linuxuser,sec=krb5,uid=1337,gid=1337 /mnt/
```

Then I've created a custom keytab file, because I did not want to enter the password of the user each time I request a Kerberos ticket:

```
$ ktutil
ktutil: addent -password -p service-user@example.com -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
ktutil: wkt custom.keytab
ktutil: exit
```

When I now request a ticket using the keytab, it also works perfectly fine and I do not have to enter a password:

```
$ kinit service-user@example.com -k -t /home/linuxuser/kerberos/custom.keytab
```

This all works great, but my problem is the following: After a reboot, the Kerberos ticket is obviously gone. So I had to request a ticket on each reboot. I've set up a cron job to take care of that, but this can't be the most sophisticated way of doing this. It seems "scrambled together" and not clean.

Now to my question: Is there a way to automatically request a Kerberos ticket each time the mount command is executed? I've searched around the internet for a bit and found that the `cifs.upcall` utility should take care of that. It basically requests a key to mount a share from userspace. I've read that you have to configure the `/etc/request-key.conf`, so that it includes a line like the following:

```
create  cifs.spnego     *       *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
```

Now I've modified that entry, so that cifs.upcall uses my custom keytab file.

```
create  cifs.spnego     *       *               /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -K /home/linuxuser/kerberos/custom.keytab -t %k
```

Sadly, the Kerberos ticket still does not get requested and the mount does not work.

So basically:

How to mount a Windows share using Kerberos automatically on each boot, without using a cron job to request a Kerberos ticket? Is using `cifs.upcall` the right way to do this and if so, why does it not work on my end?